# OpenGL (ES) -- Storing and using a color array in a VBO, and applying it to a VBO triangle

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es

How can this be done? This code isn't working:

```
//////////INIT COLOR VBO FOR USE WITH A TRIANGLE    
triColorBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(3 * 4
    * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();        

float[] colors = { 
1f, 0f, 0f, 1f,
0f, 1f, 0f, 1f, 
0f, 0f, 1f, 1f,};

triColorBuffer.put(colors);
triColorBuffer.flip();
int[] buffer = new int[1];
gl11.glGenBuffers(1, buffer, 0);
colorPointerTri = buffer[0];
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorPointerTri);
gl11.glBufferData(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triColorBuffer.capacity() 
    * 4, triColorBuffer, GL11.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

////////////DRAW USING COLOR VBO
gl11.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
gl11.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl11.glPushMatrix();

gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexPointerTri);
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexPointerTri);
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorPointerTri);
gl11.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
gl11.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
gl11.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
gl11.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
gl11.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

gl11.glPopMatrix();
gl11.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
gl11.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

The triangle draws VBO'd or nor, and the color gradient (glcolorpointer) works non VBO'd, but I can't get the VBO'd triangle to color using a color pointer (VBO or without). Help Appreciated.

Comment: You should post your VBO upload code and the array structure, and also define exactly what doesn't work (and what do you expect).

Comment: Will do.... I didn't want to post too much code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are binding the vertex buffer and right after that you bind the color buffer. When you now call glColor/VertexPointer, both colors and vertices are sourced from the color buffer. You need to write:

```
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexPointerTri);
gl11.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorPointerTri);
gl11.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
```

As the gl...Pointer command uses the buffer that is currently bound.

Answer (score 3):

Please do correct me if I'm wrong, I started out with VBOs just 15mins ago.

Anyway, it seems so you have to use VBOs 'in two'. First you bind your data/array, and right after that tell GL context what you just gave it. Took me a good a while to read through this [source file](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/SpriteMethodTest/src/com/android/spritemethodtest/Grid.java#240) to figure out what was going on and truly hope I didn't misunderstood it totally. Excerpt from that file;

```
if (useTexture) {
    gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mTextureCoordBufferIndex);
    gl11.glTexCoordPointer(2, mCoordinateType, 0, 0);
}            
if (useColor) {
    gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mColorBufferIndex);
    gl11.glColorPointer(4, mCoordinateType, 0, 0);
}
```

In your code, you're binding 3 times and right after start switching what was binded. I don't know what exactly happens there but I would give it a go to try e.g.

```
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexPointerTri);
gl11.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorPointerTri);
gl11.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexPointerTri);
gl11.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

Also from what I've seen it shouldn't do any harm if you unbind your arrays after rendering. Maybe it's in your code not copy/pasted here, but just in case.

```
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Comment: I think I know what you're talking about. But eventually we'll get there  :)

Comment: You need not bind the element array buffer right before the draw call, as it is another binding point than the array buffer. No problem with your code, just for clarity.